# trying to delete image from production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have an image that is persisting in its availability (presumably through the Rails asset cache?). Even after I ran 
`git rm my-image.png` locally (which for some reason didn't create a Git change in my git status) and then running `rm my-image.png` locally and then running `rm my-image.png` on the production server in both my `app/assets` folder and `public/images/` folders.

How is it that the asset is still being served?
Is there a way to actually delete it for good?

Comment: You probably need to precompile assets for production and redeploy.

Comment: And also, just removing the image might not solve the problem for any browsers that has already picked up the image. Assets are cached using a far-future-expire-header, so browsers, who are allowed to aggressively cache the image will not look at it again, and just serve it from the cache.